# I have a matrix of contiguity and a matrix of colonial dyads. How do I use the first matrix to find the contiguity relationships for the colonies?

Tags: r, network-analysis

I have one larger matrix that uses the Direct Contiguity database from correlates of war, with the intention of creating a contiguity network. I have a second, smaller matrix of coloniser-colony dyads. I can find the weighted geodesic path lengths between all countries in the first matrix using igraph's distances() function. Is there a way I can subset these distances only for the colonial dyads, while keeping the other countries in the contiguity matrix? I need the other countries, because removing them would create misleading contiguity relationships for the colonial dyads. I just need the distance between colonial dyads.

Below is the creation of the matrices.

```
## Colonial dyad matrix
col_dyad <- read.csv("colonial_dyads.csv")


states <-unique(c(as.character(col_dyad$Empire),as.character(col_dyad$Country)))


col_mat <- matrix(0,nrow=length(states),ncol=length(states)) # 
    rownames(col_mat) <-     states
        colnames(col_mat) <-     states
for(i in 1:dim(col_dyad)[1]){
    col_mat[as.character(col_dyad$Empire[i]),as.character(col_dyad$Country[i])] <- col_mat[as.character(col_dyad$Empire[i]),as.character(col_dyad$Country[i])]+1
}
```

```
# Contiguity matrix
cont <- read.csv("contdird.csv")
cont <-  unique(cont[,c("state1ab","state2ab","conttype","year")])

cont <- filter(cont, year == 2016)


cont_states <- unique(c(as.character(conttype_data$state1ab),as.character(conttype_data$state2ab)))

## Creates square matrix
cont_mat <- matrix(0, nrow = length(cont_states), ncol = length(cont_states))
rownames(cont_mat) <-     cont_states
        colnames(cont_mat) <-     cont_states
        
        dim(cont_mat)
        

conttype_data <- cont %>% uncount(cont$conttype)

##Fills in matrix with uncounted data

for(i in 1:dim(conttype_data)[1]){
cont_mat[as.character(conttype_data$state1ab[i]),as.character(conttype_data$state2ab[i])] <- cont_mat[as.character(conttype_data$state1ab[i]),as.character(conttype_data$state2ab[i])]+1

}
```

I've tried creating a union() (igraph) network between them, but when I add up the paths between the country dyads, it also adds the colonial paths, which inflates the numbers, or I get an error for vector lengths not matching up.

```
col_net1 <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(col_mat)
cont_net1 <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(cont_mat)


col_cont_net <- union(col_net1, cont_net1)

geodesics <- distances(col_cont_net, mode = "out", weights = conttype_data$conttype)
geodesics
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You maximize your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  may help.